# Installing library to subdirectory within /usr/local/lib?

Tags: software-installation, libraries, development

I have a large library of my own with many components or "submodules" (similarly to how boost has many components) which I am setting up install rules for within CMake.

Let's say my library is called myLib version 1.2.3. My question is, since my library will produce many `.a` or `.so` output files due to the several components, is it acceptable to install these files into a subfolder within `/usr/local/lib/` e.g. into `/usr/local/lib/myLib/` or `/usr/local/lib/myLib-1.2.3/`?

I am usually a Windows developer but am dual-booting Ubuntu and want installation of my library for other developers on Unix to be as hassle-free as possible.

I noticed the `libboost-all-dev` installs all files directly into `/usr/local/lib/`, however I see that this can make the lib folder quite messy. Does it matter if I "add clutter" to this folder with many library files?

Also, I am contemplating whether my library files should have the version in the title. What is the standard for this? e.g. `myLib-1.2.3.a` vs `myLib.a`. I know this is slightly off-topic to the main question, but if I install directly to the lib folder, then it might be advantageous to have version numbers in the file etc. so I think it is slightly related.

Also - apologies if this is the wrong thread, as I know it is heavily related to software engineering, but I assumed it had more to do with Linux folder structure than anything else!

Answer (score -1):

If you wish to install libraries anywhere other than the system lib directories, and for other users to access them, then create a text file in `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/` which contains the directory where you are placing your libs, then run `ldconfig`. The system will then correctly pick your libs, provided there are no clashes. There is no requirement to mess around with compiler & linker settings other than supplying `-l`/`-L` settings to compiler/linker.